# Running Python from R

Tags: python, r, shiny, rstudio

I am aware that there are multiple libraries for both languages (R/Python) to call modules from the other one. I am looking for a way to have the backend of my code running in python mainly because of .pyc and speed, and also the front end running in R so I can have a Shiny app. I couldn't find a way to make python machine for the backend. If anyone knows how to do it in R/Rstudio please respond.

Comment: This question seems fairly broad. What exactly is Python supposed to be running? If you want a web app project, you can use something like Django (Python) and include a the R Shiny app as a web app. But again, please explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: you may want to check out `rPython`

Comment: “mainly because of .pyc and speed” — This strikes me a as a bad reason: Python performance is generally abysmal and only slightly better than R’s in general. Furthermore, `.pyc` doesn’t really improve performance all that much and R actually has a superior equivalent via compiled code simply by putting your code into a package.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any good benchmarks on it's speed, but the [reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) package is the best way I know of to pass data to and from a python script without using a webserver. It lets you import python objects into R where they will act like R objects, accepting arguments and returning values.

There were a few wonky problems that I had when I just wanted to run functions from a single file. It ran into problems with import statements and multiple functions that called on each other. What worked well was to run the `import` statements separately (see the `sapply()` statement below) and to merge all the code in my python script into a single object. This worked nicely and seemed about as fast as running it in python normally (though I haven't done any real benchmarking)

```
library(reticulate)
use_python(python = '/usr/bin/python') # optionally specify python location

# Import statements are here, not in the file
sapply(c("import mysql.connector", "import re"), py_run_string)

# File contains only the definition of  class MismatchFinder
source_python("python_script.py") 

# Now we can call on that python object from R
result <- MismatchFinder()$find_mismatch(arg1, arg2)
```

My impression is that it might be simpler if you make your python code into a module and load it with: `py_module <- import_from_path('my_python_module', path = 'PATH')` but I didn't try that.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are looking for is the code below. It will run a python script in R.

```
system('python3 file_name.py')
```

Comment: Does this solve the "backend" issue? From OP's question, it seems there is some background activity (e.g. server) that needs to run in Python, and only a web app needed to run in R. Your solution works well for scripts, but if there is something more interactive that needs to be run, this solution would come into some problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response. using system() is not sufficient since you can't actually pass through any argument, you can simply run a script. If there is another way that you are aware of please let me know.